# Next intl 404 translations loaded on all non-404 pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-intl

im using Next.js to create a web application and next-intl to translate it to multiple languages. I created the not-found.tsx file to handle 404 errors.

What im seeing now if i inspect the html of the 200 pages is that the translations of the 404 page, are loaded as next js  tags (self.__next_f.push).

How can i not load this translations and make them load only when 404 pages render?